# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). Error on using bing search

Tags: python, search-engine, bing

I have a simple script to get urls from bing search.

```
import bingsearch

bingsearch.API_KEY='mykey'

r = bingsearch.request("JohnDalton")
print r.status_code

print r[0]['Url']
```

The bingsearch.py file is:

```
import requests
import urllib2

URL = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/SearchWeb/Web?Query='%(query)s'&$top=50&$format=json"
API_KEY = 'mykey'
def request(query, **params):
    r = requests.get(URL % {'query': query}, auth=('', API_KEY))
    return r.json()['d']['results']
```

How do i avoid the error mentioned before. Thanks.

Comment: can you print the valueof r.content before r.json() in request function?

Comment: it gives me the error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'status_code'".

Answer (score 0):

It's an auth problem, you are not getting any results so nothing to decode.

this might be the error it gets:
The authorization type you provided is not supported.  Only Basic and OAuth are supported
401

I think in auth dictionary

```
r = requests.get(URL % {'query': query}, auth=('', API_KEY))
```

you should pass username as well instead of empty string.

**Edit:**

Looks like username and passwd both are identical for azure api. Try passing

```
r = requests.get(URL % {'query': query}, auth=(API_KEY, API_KEY))
```

**Edit2:**

Ok whats the output of this

```
import requests

URL = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/SearchWeb/Web?Query='%(query)s'&$top=50&$format=json"
API_KEY = 'mykey'
def request(query, **params):
    r = requests.get(URL % {'query': query}, auth=('', API_KEY))
    print r.content, r.status_code
    return r.json()['d']['results']


r = request("JohnDalton")
print r.status_code

print r[0]['Url']
```

Comment: Yeah same error, except with "The authorization type you provided is not supported.  Only Basic and OAuth are supported
401" printed.

Comment: have you tried running this query on browser, just to double check if your key is fine?
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/SearchWeb/Web?Query=%27dalton%27&$top=50&$format=json